# Get groups user is memberof azure cli

Tags: command-line-interface, azure-ad-b2b, azure-cloud-shell

To know whether the user is a part of any Azure ad group or not I used below Azure cli command

```
az ad group member check --group groupname --member-id ******
```

This gave me output with warning like below:

```
az : WARNING: The underlying Active Directory Graph API will be replaced by Microsoft Graph API in Azure CLI 2.37.0. Please carefully review all breaking changes introduced during this migration:  
https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/microsoft-graph-migration
At line:1 char:1  
+ az ad group member check --group *** --member-id **** ...  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
+ CategoryInfo  : NotSpecified: (WARNING: The un...graph-migration:String) [], RemoteException  
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError  
 
{  
"odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/******/$metadata#Edm.Boolean"  
"value": true  
}
```

For every command I am running in cli I get this warning which annoys me. How to get rid of the **warning** and get only the output?

I also want to get the list of groups the user is a memberof?
Is there any command to achieve that in cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below:***

To avoid the warning message, please use **`--only-show-errors`** command like below:

```bash
az ad group member check --group Test_Group1 --member-id User_Object_ID --only-show-errors
```

**Response (Without warning):**

```bash
{  
"odata.metadata":https://graph.windows.net/XXXX/$metadata#Edm.Boolean" 
"value": true  
}
```

[image]

***To get the list of groups the user is a memberof, please use the below command:***

```bash
az ad user get-member-groups --id User_Object_ID  --only-show-errors
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[az ad user | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-user-get-member-groups)